# C programming -Whats the difference between dividing inside a variable and dividing two variables?

Tags: c, variables, division

So I am trying to learn how to divide fractions. I am confused why dividing variables gives the correct result, and dividing the numbers themselves gives an incorrect result. I have tried to searching on here and couldn't find anything relevant. Here is an image to show why I am talking about.
[image]

Comment: `1/3` is integer division, will give a result of `0` because of truncation. Did you mean `1.0/3.0` ?

Comment: In the future, please don't post images of text. Copy-paste the text, as text, instead.

Comment: Ok, thank you! will do! I understand now thank you!

Comment: [don't put images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `1 / 3` is an ***integer*** expression. You divide two `int` values. That leads to *truncation*.

Try e.g. `1.0 / 3.0` instead.

Comment: Just to be precise: it truncates towards zero, thus if one operand is negative, the result is actually higher than one might expect.